# search form in new custom page template not working

Tags: php, wordpress, search, custom-post-type, search-form

I'm working in Tv shows and movies theme. I have created new page template to display all movies and anther page template to show the  tv shows (both custom post type).
My search form if any one use it from the index page working fine and shows the result in search.php
but if you are in movies page or anther pages the search form takes you to the index page (404 page not created yet)

I'm using this code in main header

```
<?php get_search_form();?>
```

this is my searchform.php

```
<form class="d-flex" role="search"  methode="get" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) ?>">
    <input class="form-control"  type="text" name="s" id="search" placeholder="<?php echo ('search in site'); ?>" 
    aria-label="<?php echo ('search'); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success search-btn" type="submit"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></button>
</form>
```

this is my search.php

```
<?php get_header(); 
$search = strtolower(get_search_query());
?> 


<?php 
$args = array(
  'taxonomy'      => array( 'series' ), // taxonomy name
  'hide_empty'    => true,
  'fields'        => 'all',
); 

$terms = get_terms( $args );

$count = count($terms);
if($count > 0){
   foreach ($terms as $term) { ?>
     get_template_part('/assests/series-temp');

   <?php } }
//code above for returning the custom term of each series post with different loop
 
$args= array(
  'post_type'=> array('movies'),
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  's' => $search
);
$titleQuery = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $titleQuery->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $titleQuery->have_posts() ){ $titleQuery->the_post(); ?>
<?php

if ( get_post_type( get_the_ID() ) == 'movies' ) {
  get_template_part('/assests/movie-temp');
} ?>
              
  <?php }  wp_reset_postdata(); } ?>



<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

where is my mistakes?? please help

Answer (score 0):

Issue 1:
in this their is a typo in this in place of "methode" write a "method"
Issue 2:
Adlso take care about the correct URL in the form action. If you are on the movies or TV shows page, you want the search to stay within that section of the site.

Comment: II changed the method word put nothing happened. and how correct the URL in action ??

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided code,Currently you are setting the action attribute to home_url('/'), which will always redirect the form submission to the homepage (/).

for that the search form works correctly regardless of the page you are on, you should set the action attribute to the URL of your search results page (search.php).

```
<form class="d-flex" role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/search.php' ) ) ?>">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="s" id="search" placeholder="<?php echo __('Search in site'); ?>" aria-label="<?php echo __('Search'); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success search-btn" type="submit"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></button>
</form>
```

Comment: still not working. if URL in my site like this (http://localhost/wordpress/) the index page search form works fine. But if it change to any page (http://localhost/wordpress/movie-list) got 404 page (just create one)

Comment: I figured out the problem, it's from admin panel. Settings > Permalink. when I change the Permalink structure to (Plain) everything's works fine from any page I can search  anything. but the is issue is the permalinks of web site looks ugly (http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=2237). If I change Permalink structure to  (Custom Structure) and choose any tags for the old issue back again. I don't really know why?